# Eloquent, how can i call relation function in other model relation function

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a problem in eloquent as you can read from title. I have a foundation and user model. All models needs to be related with foundation. I do not want to create a pivot table for each model so i wanna call user model's foundation relation function in other models' foundation relation function. You can read example code:

```
class User extends Model{

   public function foundations(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(Foundation::class);
   }

}

class Personnel extends Model{

  public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

   public function foundations(){
      return $this->user->foundations();
   }

}
```

When i run

```
Personnel::with("foundations")->first();
```

this code return wrong foundations.

**Edit 1 = In datatable I retrieve datas with foundations() function. So I must use like this => {Model}->foundations()

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
Personnel::with('user.foundations')->first()
```

The period indicates that you want to eager load the relations relation as well.

Comment: I use dynamic models on same function so i must use foundations() relation function. I edit the question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you show the controller or wherever you're using it? If you load it like this (my answer), you can get user like this: `$user = $personnel->user;` and you can get the foundations like this: `$foundations = $personnel->user->foundations`, assumming you store the result of the query in `$personnel` variable.

Comment: I get the dynamic model's data like this:

$this->eloquentModel->whereHas('foundations', function ($table) {
                        return $table->where('slug', $this->foundationSlug);
                    });

$this->eloquentModel means a Model. So this function is dynamic and i need foundations function in all model.

Comment: I'm sorry but you're not making this easy for anyone. I have no idea if $this is used in controller, if you're calling ->eloquentModel as property or method, where you get $this->foundationSlug from. And I still don't understand what you mean by "dynamic model". If you want help you'll need to explain how you're doing things a little bit better (and put some effort in formatting please). Good luck

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes. Formatted code :

`$this->eloquentModel->whereHas('foundations', function ($table) { 
            return $table->where('slug', $this->foundationSlug);
 });`

"$this->eloquentModel" refers an Eloquent Model for example User or Personnel model in this example. This is just an Eloquent Model. Dynamic means this code run on every Eloquent Model. So every model has to have foundations() function. I hope it is more clear. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you really want this `foundations` relationship on Personnel model, even though they are not connected at all? This is not going to be possible. You could make an accessor for same purpose, but there is no relationship that would make this possible. Meaning you won't be able to use `Personnel::with('foundations')`.

Comment: It was nice to agree. Yes, you understood correctly.  Thank you for your answers. May the force be with you @devk

Comment: May the force be with you @devk ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
Personnel::with("user.foundations")->first();
```

Dont need `foundations()` in Personnel Model.

Comment: I use dynamic models on same function so i must use foundations() relation function. I edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

We can call the foundations' relation method by chaining rule.

```
return $this->with('user.foundations')->first();
```

This return the current user with many foundations.